# Identify entity key in ndb based on a property, then delete the entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm attempting a ndb query which identifies a user account (Account entity) based on an email address, and then delete that entity. Account entities have parent of access_lvl.

The following code doesn't seem to be picking up the Account key properly and/or is using the delete() statement incorrectly.

```
def access_lvl_key(website_sect_name=DEFAULT_WEBSITE_NAME):
    """Constructs a Datastore key for an Access_lvl entity with website_sect_name."""
    return ndb.Key('Access_lvl', website_sect_name)


class Account(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual access_lvl entry."""
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    nickname = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    author = ndb.UserProperty()

    @classmethod
    def find_account(self, _email, _website_sect_name):
        website_key = ndb.Key('Acess_lvl', _website_sect_name)
        account = Account.query(Account.email == _email, ancestor=website_key)
        return account.get()



class Deluser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        _website_sect_name = self.request.get('website_sect_name', DEFAULT_WEBSITE_NAME)
        _email = self.request.get('email')

        account = Account.find_account(_email, _website_sect_name)
        ndb.Key('Account', account).delete()
```

Ultimately I would like to create an account-based access list for portions of a GAE website which matches a Google-authenticated account against an ndb account list. If anyone happens to have any links for that I'd appreciate that as well.

Comment: `The following code doesn't seem to be picking up the Account key properly and/or is using the delete() statement incorrectly.` can you be more clear please? What exactly does it (not) do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect spelling of Access:

```
website_key = ndb.Key('Acess_lvl', _website_sect_name)
```

To delete a ndb entity that have ancestor, Syntax is

```
ndb.Key('Ancestor_name', ancestor_key.id(), Entity, entity.key.id()).delete()
```

In your case,

```
ndb.Key('Access_lvl', access_lvl_key(_website_sect_name).id(), Account, account.key.id()).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect spelling of `Access`:

`website_key = ndb.Key('Acess_lvl', _website_sect_name)`